# Convert URL into TinyURL in iPhone

Tags: iphone, url, tinyurl

I want to programmatically convert a URl to TinyURL in iPhone. How to do this?

Comment: you need some a hash function that make the string smaller. see this Idea in C# might give you a hint [See](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1116860/whats-the-best-way-to-create-a-short-hash-similiar-to-what-tiny-url-does)

Answer (score 5):

Tiny URL has a simple API that you can use, it's very simple

Just send this request with your URL

http://tinyurl.com/api-create.php?url=http://yourURL.com/

It will return a tiny URL with your link

Edit: here's a working example, this is a synchronous request though so it can make your app unresponsive if it takes too long.

```
NSString *origUrl = @"http://stackoverflow.com";
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://tinyurl.com/api-create.php?url=%@", origUrl]]; 
NSURLRequest *request = [ NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url
                                      cachePolicy:NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringCacheData
                                  timeoutInterval:10.0 ];
NSError *error;
NSURLResponse *response;
NSData *myUrlData = [ NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request
                                   returningResponse:&response
                                               error:&error];
NSString *myTinyUrl = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:myUrlData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
//do stuff with url
[myTinyUrl release];
```

Comment: I like your answer, but what if the server was down or too busy doing the request at that time? @Warrior application will not work if he completely depend on tinyUrl api.

Comment: @AhmadTK: like you, I initially got a very long wait trying Hector's link, but it seems to be responding quite quickly now so it most likely was a temporary glitch.

Comment: Well I didn't give a specific code example right now as I am posting from my phone. I would assume that you would have a fallback on your http request in case of a timeout or other error

Answer (score 3):

This might help: [tiny url api](http://www.richardcastera.com/blog/creating-a-tinyurl-with-tinyurl-api)

Answer (score 0):

Way easier and works in ios7

```
NSError *error
NSString *tinyURL =  [NSString stringWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://tinyurl.com/api-create.php?url=%@", YOUR-URL]]
                                                  encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding error:&error];

// error handling here..
```