# iphone+Webservice which gives shorten url in response

Tags: iphone

I want the web service in json OR in xml which gives the shorten url in response.

I have  to implement the web service in iPhone application.

Let me know of any web services which do the following:

If I give  as the request

Then it will return **http://goo.gl/fbsS** in response.

I found this:
https://www.googleapis.com/urlshortener/v1/url?shortUrl=http://goo.gl/fbsS

But this is actually the reverse of what I want, in that I have to pass the shortened url and it gives the long url in response

Like this:-

```
{
 "kind": "urlshortener#url",
 "id": "http://goo.gl/fbsS",
 "longUrl": "http://www.google.com/",
 "status": "OK"
}
```

Answer (score 3):

try TinyURL:

http://json-tinyurl.appspot.com/

[obj c / iphone related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5716587/covert-url-into-tiny-url-in-iphone)

Answer (score 0):

You can use this to get the shorten url:

http://api.bit.ly/v3/shorten?login=XXXX&apikey=XXXXXlongUrl=http://www.stackoverflow.com&format=xml