# How to create simple short hash value? C#

Tags: c#, hash

How to create simple hash value? For example I have string "TechnologyIsCool" and how to have hash value from this string?

I want to do some method like:

```
public string HashThis(string value)
{
    string hashResult = string.Empty;

    ...

    return hashResult;
}
```

and call this method like:

```
string hash = HashThis("TechnologyIsCool");
```

and after that have hash like "5qazws".

Comment: Why you don't want to use String.GetHashCode()?

Comment: What kind of hash? An indexing hash? A cryptographic hash?

Comment: I want to understand how work the short links. Is it should be custom hash?

Comment: My guess is that the folks doing shortened links are storing the original link in a database and then [Base64](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.convert.tobase64string.aspx) encoding the identification assigned to the row.  A hash does not produce a unique value and collisions wouldn't make TinyURL too popular, e.g. a link that gets you either kittens or the national budget.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Use [String.GetHashCode Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.gethashcode.aspx)

```
 public static void Main() 
    {
        DisplayHashCode( "Abcdei" );
    }

static void DisplayHashCode( String Operand )
{
    int     HashCode = Operand.GetHashCode( );
    Console.WriteLine("The hash code for \"{0}\" is: 0x{1:X8}, {1}",
                      Operand, HashCode );
}
```

Comment: The hashcode can vary on different runtimes. Some warnings that apply to this solution can be found here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1116860/whats-the-best-way-to-create-a-short-hash-similiar-to-what-tiny-url-does

Answer (score 6):

Use `GetHashCode();`

```
public string HashThis(string value)
{
    return hashResult = value.GetHashCode();
}
```

Comment: The hashcode can vary on different runtimes. Some warnings that apply to this solution can be found here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1116860/whats-the-best-way-to-create-a-short-hash-similiar-to-what-tiny-url-does

Answer (score 2):

No you cannot use String.GetHashCode() because this does not guarantee to return the same hash on the same string every time.

Comment: What will guarantee to return the same hash on the same string every time?

Comment: Answer: The function written by yourself.